# How to Enable PO Link on Sales Order screen

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to change the logic that enables the "PO Link" action/button on the Sales Order lines.  I'm not finding where the code that controls the enable/disable lives.  Is it controlled by a workflow?  If so, where?

I've tried the below but the SetEnable() is being overridden, apparently.

```
 public class MySOOrderEntryExt : 
 PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.SO.GraphExtensions.SOOrderEntryExt.POLinkDialog, 
 PX.Objects.SO.GraphExtensions.SOOrderEntryExt.PurchaseSupplyBaseExt, SOOrderEntry>
 {
    public void _(Events.RowSelected<SOOrder> e)
    {
        //Base.Actions["pOSupplyOK"].SetEnabled(false);  //Doesn't work.
        Base.Actions["pOSupplyOK"].SetVisible(false);
        
    }
    
}
```

Any ideas would be great.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The control consists of 2 components.  In the ASPX in the ActionBar of the grid, teh button is defined as:

```
<px:PXToolBarButton Text="PO Link" DependOnGrid="grid" StateColumn="IsPOLinkAllowed">
  <AutoCallBack Command="POSupplyOK" Target="ds" ></AutoCallBack>
</px:PXToolBarButton>
```

The StateColumn refers to the field that determines if the action/button is enabled or not.  This is defined in SOLine in the field IsPOLinkAllowed as:

```
#region IsPOLinkAllowed
public abstract class isPOLinkAllowed : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<isPOLinkAllowed> { }

[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<Case<Where<SOLine.pOCreate, Equal<True>, And<SOLine.operation, Equal<SOOperation.issue>>>, True>, False>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Invisible, Visible = false, Enabled = false)]
[PXBool]
public virtual bool? IsPOLinkAllowed
{
    get;
    set;
}
#endregion
```

The PXFormula indicates that the POCreate field must be true and the operation of the Sales Order be an Issue.

The simplest way to modify this behavior likely is to change the attributes on the field via a DAC extension or CacheAttached in the graph to result in *true* when you want it enabled.